# .NET MVC - jQuery Not Rendering When Published

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery, Bootstrap.js, and datatables in my project and they all render fine when running locally. However, when I publish to our DEV environment (IIS 7.5) I get an error that Bootsrap and datatables require jQuery, as if the server didn't serve up jQuery. I have attempted to reference all of these files several different ways:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") // this pulled in the min version that errored out for another reason, but at least ran
```

All of these still produce the same error when it reaches Bootsrap and datatables JS files. jQuery is undefined. I've confirmed that the jQuery files are deployed to the server, and are in the correct location. I've also confirmed that they aren't being reference more than once.

This is my current set up for all my JS references, happening in the  of my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: can you check in developer tools if your files are actually coming to the browser OR are they a 404. In that case you might need to change your base url.

Comment: jQuery, bootstrap, and datatables are all coming into the browser with a 200 response.

Comment: Check that you have rolled reference files to server.

Comment: All my scripts are on the server, and the files referencing those scripts are there as well (_Layout.cshtml, and all my views).

It says all files are loading into the browser when I view the responses via the network debugger, but when I look at the script debugger jQuery isn't listed.

Comment: I am getting this error in jquery:

Expected identifier

In this block:

`jQuery.fn.ready = function( fn ) {

 readyList
  .then( fn )

  // Wrap jQuery.readyException in a function so that the lookup
  // happens at the time of error handling instead of callback
  // registration.
  .catch( function( error ) {
   jQuery.readyException( error );
  } );

 return this;
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our company had a group policy set to force the display of intranet sites in Compatibility View.

I added this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" />
```